# How to install Debian packages on Alpine?

Tags: ubuntu, influxdb, alpine-linux

How to install Debian packages on Alpine?

For example:

```
wget https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb_0.13.0_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i influxdb_0.13.0_armhf.deb
```

Answer (score 37):

**Good news:**

`alpine` now has `dpkg` package available in its repository and you can install it by `apk add dpkg` and you can use `dpkg -i *.deb` to install the `deb` you want.

Comment: `/bin/sh: dpkg: not found`
--- am I missing something?

Comment: Did you install `dpkg` use `apk add dpkg`?

Comment: dpkg: error: failed to open package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' for reading: No such file or directory How to create the status file on alpine?

Comment: It seems to be a plain text file, maybe just `touch` that file and see how it goes?

Comment: better answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/594431/391534

Answer (score 5):

Alpine Linux is not a Debian derivate (luckily), so it does not support Debian packages.

Alpine doesn't provide a package for influxdb (yet), so you can create one or install influxdb from sources.

Comment: Why is that a good thing that Alpine is not compatible with Debian? This makes life hard for people who want to switch.

Comment: well it's a completely different linux distribution so why would you expect it in any way to be compatible with debian packages? how often do you see kangaroos mating with whales?

Comment: That is not a strange expectation.  There are plenty of distributions that use common package managers.  For example, Ubuntu and Kali use Debian packages.  RPMs are used by Red Hat (obviously), SUSE, and Mandriva linux distributions.

Comment: Alpine's theme is: "Small. Simple. Secure.". Adding deb support would conflict with it. There are plenty of alternatives for Alpine. If space is not an issue, why not simply use a ubuntu server image?

Comment: @mace for me it's centralization and latest versions, The way alpine structure APKs are so good as making blender latest down to 77.51 installed size due to **separation** of dependancies, that ones could be used by other packages olso, so that allow for less proccess replication and more of hardware effetiency for large scale setup also, but it still lake many packages